# Migrating Meta Pixels from website to GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

Question about migrating manually inserted Meta pixels/Events to GTM. Any feedback is much appreciated!

We manually installed the FB Pixel and manually created events b installing the code into our website a few months ago.

Now, we want to migrate **all of these events**, including the pixel loading code to GTM.

My question: If I delete the existing pixels loading/event creation code on the website and create the appropriate tags/trigger in GTM:

a) will those 'new GTM' events be pushed as new events to Meta

b) will the pixel have to re-learn?

c) will I lose the data flowing into my existing ads?

For example, if I delete the following code from the website and create the appropriate tag in GTM how will these events change?

```
<script>
fbq('track', 'Lead');
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

a) No, there is no magic whatsoever. Inspect how the network requests to Meta look right now, then reimplement them in GTM and in GTM preview on your lower env make sure the GTM-spawned network requests are exactly like they are on prod. As long as the requests are the same, the endpoint won't know the difference.

b) No, it won't know anything has changed. Exceeept... Note that some adblockers may block GTM, but allow facebook, so the volume of conversions may be slightly lower, but that shouldn't affect FB's learning.

c) You may lose some data, but not much since most of the adblockers block both, facebook and GTM. The data loss is likely to be low enough to be immeasurable and insignificant.

But again, during the development, test your network requests if you don't want surprises. The data should not change unless you make mistakes.